# How to select distinct based on multiple values for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel this is a very easy task and I am grossly overthinking it. I have looked and looked nothing seems to answer my question. My question is simple, how do I select distinct on one column, based on multiple values of another column:

Table:

| Customers | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Orange |
| Bob | Apple |
| Sally | Orange |
| Sally | Lemon |
| Sam | Lemon |
| Sam | Apple |
| Tom | Orange |
| Tom | Lime |

The table above shows a new line every time a customer purchases a fruit. How do I select distinct for customers who either purchased an (Orange AND Apple) OR (Orange AND Lemon).

The end result should only show: Bob and Sally.

Comment: What happens if you have have STEVE: Orange, Apple and Lemon?  or RANDY: Orange, Apple, and Lime?  would both of those be included in your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't care if a user has all 3 you still want them returned. or if they have more than 2 but at least orange and one of the other 2.

Just using a simple join.  Get those that are Orange and those that are either Apple or lemon--> join--> distinct.

```
SELECT Distinct A.Customers
FROM dbo.yourTable A
INNER JOIN dbo.yourTable B
 on A.Customer = B.Customer
WHERE A.Fruit = 'Orange'
  and B.Fruit in ('Apple','Lemon')
```

Assuming an index on dbo.yourTable.Fruit... should be pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```sql
SELECT Customers
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Customers
HAVING (COUNT(CASE Fruit WHEN 'Orange' THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND COUNT(CASE Fruit WHEN 'Apple' THEN 1 END) >= 1)
    OR (COUNT(CASE Fruit WHEN 'Orange' THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND COUNT(CASE Fruit WHEN 'Lemon' THEN 1 END) >= 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Customer
FROM tablename
WHERE Fruit IN ('Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon')
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) > 0 -- the customer bought 'Orange' at least once
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT Fruit) > 1 -- the customer bought at least 2 of the 3 fruits
```

If you want to exclude the case that the customer has bought all 3 fruits:

```
SELECT Customer
FROM tablename
WHERE Fruit IN ('Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon')
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) > 0 -- the customer bought 'Orange' at least once
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT Fruit) = 2 -- the customer bought exactly 2 of the 3 fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

A fun alternative using the underappreciated INTERSECT

```
SELECT Person FROM YourTable WHERE Fruit = 'Apple' 
INTERSECT -- INTERSECT discards duplicates
SELECT Person FROM YourTable WHERE Fruit = 'Orange'

UNION -- UNION also does an implicit DISTINCT

SELECT Person FROM YourTable WHERE Fruit = 'Lemon' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT Person FROM YourTable WHERE Fruit = 'Orange'
```

Comment: ..one intersect would suffice: `orange intersect (apple,lemon)`

Comment: I think this actually is the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Customers, count (distinct Fruit)
from YourTable 
having count (distinct Fruits) > 1
group by Customers
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**